# What are the parameters for training SVM

Tags: machine-learning

I'm doing software using machine learning with SVM using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/machine_learning

according to the example of SVM:

```
svm.train({
    C : 1.1, // default : 1.0. C in SVM. 
    tol : 1e-5, // default : 1e-4. Higher tolerance --> Higher precision 
    max_passes : 20, // default : 20. Higher max_passes --> Higher precision 
    alpha_tol : 1e-5, // default : 1e-5. Higher alpha_tolerance --> Higher precision 

    kernel : { type: "polynomial", c: 1, d: 5}
    // default : {type : "gaussian", sigma : 1.0} 
    // {type : "gaussian", sigma : 0.5} 
    // {type : "linear"} // x*y 
    // {type : "polynomial", c : 1, d : 8} // (x*y + c)^d 
    // Or you can use your own kernel. 
    // kernel : function(vecx,vecy) { return dot(vecx,vecy);} 
});
```

the parameter C tells the SVM optimization how much you want to avoid misclassifying each training example.

I do not understand the other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look at the equation of the soft-margin `C-SVM`:

[image: Primal C-SVM]

It points out that `C` defines the trade-off between missclassifications and margin. This must be choosen sufficiently large depending on your data. What you'll also see here is the `eps>0` parameter. This could possibly be your `tolerance` parameter and defines the error to the  which is weighted by `C` parameter in the objective function.

For the `kernel parameters`, take a look at the dual problem for the `SVM`:

[image: Dual SVM]

You'll see the term `K(x_i,x_j)`. This is called the `Kernel-Function`. This function allows the SVM to learn non-linear descision boundaries. So if your data is not linearly separatable, you can use such a function to tranform your data, actually it's `dot-product`, into an higher dimensional feature space to separate them there. Just take a look at this guide, it will teach you the basics about the training process of an SVM and some best practices:

[https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)

Comment: wonderful answer but, I still do not understand the parameters tol : 1e-5,    max_passes : 20, alpha_tol : 1e-5,

Comment: Interestingly, this is not well documented. The doc just says that one shouldn't touch them if one is "not a pro" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/svm). I'm sure this is for the optimization algorithm but it may not be the SMO algorithm. They also offer libSVM, which I can recommend. It uses the SMO algorithm and it's well documented and you won't have those parameters. Take a look: https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsvm-js. The research community also uses this quite a lot in matlab, C++ or Java.

Comment: i have a question, each row of training witch is him name?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: how to define sigma for kernel rbf?, 
you recommend me some book please

Comment: You use a technique called grid-search. You’ll find it by googling. It’s quite easy :)

Comment: i have my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125820/optimal-sigma-for-the-rbf-kernel please help me.

Comment: i should to work with param_grid = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
 ]          ?

Comment: Try it as I suggested in the answer to your question