# Optimal sigma for the RBF kernel?

Tags: svm

How can I choose an optimal sigma for the RBF kernel?

I'm using a classifier of a single class, 
on which to base, what parameters to take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use some sort of [Grid-Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization). It's a technique where you evaluate the performance of the two parameters at once. For your SVM there is `sigma` and `C`. Hence, you perform an exhaustive search over the parameter space where each axis represents an parameter and a point in it, is a tuple of two parameter values `(C_i, sigma_i)`.

So, to perform it, you simply choose a set for `C`: `{C_1,..., C_n}` and for `sigma`: `{sigma_1,..., sigma_n}` and train and afterwards test it for every pair of parameters in the two sets `(C_i, sigma_i)`.

This actually will take quite a long time so I suggest you to try something similar instead:

[LibSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for example offers [K-Fold Cross-Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation), so pic a set of `sigma` values, define a fixed `K` (maybe 5 to 10) and run cross-validation to get a good estimate of `C`. Document the `C` parameter and the accuracy score. After you applied this to all elements of you set of `sigma` values, choose the pair of parameters which achived the highest accuracy during each cross-validation procedure.

**Note:**
I suggest you not to use the SVM to one-class problems. Even when there is a formal definition for it, the basic SVM algorithm needs two classes to determine an optimal boundary. Hence, I'd suggest you to create a `catch-all` class and to transform your one-class problem into a two-class problem.

Comment: You can answer all your questions by simply using google. Please start to study the subject.

Comment: I do not know how to formulate the data for oneClass, I am confused with one vs one and one vs all, please helpme!

Comment: I told you: don’t use one class svm. You used it in a case where you didn’t had to. You tried solving XOR, wich is a binary problem so one can use a basic svm. One vs all is just for multiclass problems (more than two classes). You simply find such answers by using google.

Comment: in https://github.com/techfort/classify-text/blob/master/node_modules/node-svm/README.md resolve the problem xor with C_SVC multi-class classifier

Comment: i edit my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421175/training-and-test-with-svm

Comment: to oneClass is used nu instead of C

Comment: can you refute why oneCLass should not be used?

Comment: Because one-Class is hard to optimize and to train. In your XOR-Problem, you have also 2 classes {0,1}. You can train your svm als binary classifier or as a one-class classifier and I’m sure that the first one outperforms the second one.

Comment: Nu is like C but with values between 0 and 1 and not 1 to infinity. Nu seems harder to optimize but I’ve never tried to compare it.

Comment: binary classifier is C_SVC? i used this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsvm-js

Comment: Nu, C etc. doesn’t matter. Seriously, did you ever studied that subject in any way? I’m sure you won’t get good results without any backroad know how.

Comment: I said it for this
async function xor() {
    const SVM = await
    require('libsvm-js');
    const svm = new SVM({
        kernel: SVM.KERNEL_TYPES.RBF, // The type of kernel I want to use
        type: SVM.SVM_TYPES.C_SVC,    // The type of SVM I want to run
        gamma: 1,                     // RBF kernel gamma parameter
        cost: 1                       // C_SVC cost parameter
    });

Answer (score 1):

depends on what kind of machine learning platform you are using. 
If you are using Weka, there is a "grid search" option available that spits out the optimal classification parameters. (i.e. for linear kernel it give you the cost function, for RBF-SVM it gives the sigma/gamma and C, etc)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html

If you are using Python, what I generally do is that I iterate through the sigma values with small steps and teat classification accuracy on each step. I then pick the sigma that resulted in the best accuracy. 
Also please note that if you optimize your SVM parameters for a given classification task, you run the risk of overfitting. However, the iterative step changes should give you a better picture as to where(if any!) overfitting happens.

Good luck!