# what does the gamma parameter in SVM.SVC() actually do

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, data-science, svc

I am trying to tune my SVM model which I built with different values of **gamma** and **C**.
Also, I have used scaled input data for my model training.

After trying with multiple combinations I did find a combination of gamma and C which gave the best accuracy,though w/o having any idea of what gamma is doing; PFB:

```
svc = svm.SVC(gamma=0.025, C=25)
```

I read the docs for getting a sense of what **gamma** actually does(which says, "*Kernel coefficient for ‘rbf’, ‘poly’ and ‘sigmoid’*") and now I'm even more confused.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer as the question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969502/what-are-the-parameters-for-training-svm. Basically C is used by SVM optimization problem as the cost for misclassified points and gamma has a different meaning depending on the kernel you are using.

Comment: @Pedrom thanks but I still cannot find any suitable answers for my question here.

Comment: I think you need to formulate the question to be more concrete. There is no enough context to tell you what gamma is doing there because you didn't mention which kernel you are using. In order to help, we need more context than just a general sense of confussion

Comment: What more context you think I should add to make this question more relevant?How can I find which kernel I'm using @Pedrom, I really have no idea. I just want to understand what effect this hyperparameter has in the modelling which I cannot find anywhere .

Answer (score 1):

From the 1.4.6 Kernel function section of https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

[image]

You can see there is a gamma parameter in polynomial, rbf and sigmoid kernel.